# Compaq Armada E500 mouse button broken

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, mouse-buttons

I have an old Armada E500, it's a nice machine for retro stuff so I'd like to use it.

However, both left and right mouse buttons are not functioning. Maybe this is a common failure, bios reset and clean install did not solve the issue.

If someone has some advice (maybe not for this particular laptop but generally) on how to attempt to repair something like this please share :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a mouse? That said, you can determine if it's hardware or OS at fault by booting from USB with Linux, e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit (no need to install the OS, just run it from the flash drive). If the touchpad buttons work there, you know it's a software issue.

Comment: It's definitely hardware. Tried some old Live CD's and they have the problem as well. And a mouse yes, but I kinda want to fix this if possible. It's in perfect condition and battery even lasts for 1.5Hrs, its more out of a collector's perspective that I want a fully functional one if I'm keeping it (I collect way to much stuff otherwise).

Comment: As do I - I'm still using an Acer Aspire One D250 when traveling. It's working well on Ubuntu 18.04 (last 32-bit version, only via update), and has depreciated to about zero. See if there was something pressing on the buttons while in storage that compressed the spring in the swiches.